# Adding a CSS callout to a tooltip

Tags: html, css

I want to show a tooltip everytime the user hovers a specific span.class
I've got some code working but unfortunately, it either shows the tooltip or... only the callout.

Here's my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5hMs8/):

**HTML:**

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<br>
<br>
<span class="rnd">[<span class="pos">suffix</span>] Some random text..............</span>
    <a href="#" class="tooltip">Tooltip<span>what a <u>rainy</u> day.</span></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tooltip {
    outline:none;
}
.tooltip strong {
    line-height:30px;
}
.tooltip:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:-160px;
    width:240px;
    line-height:16px;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    color:#EEE;
    background:#000;
}
.tooltip span {
    border-radius:2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px #666;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.pos {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none
}
.pos:hover:before {
    display:inline;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
    bottom: -20px;
    content:"";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I would like it to look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lu3G8/

Comment: Why don't you try JavaScript!! it's much easier

Comment: In your code, where and when should the tooltip appear ??

Comment: @MujtabaFathel I can do it javascript... javascript only (no jquery). Hover over Tooltip and Suffix

Comment: @Mujtaba No. Misusing a language is not a good idea.

Comment: Could you post an image of what you want it to look like? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @bjb568 I want it to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu3G8/  (which I can't use since I can't put HTML tags inside the CSS content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5hMs8/2/

```
<span class="tooltip pos">suffix<span>An affix that follows the element to <u>which</u> it is added, as <i>-ly</i>  in <i>kindly</i>.</span></span>
```

I changed the CSS (`.pos:hover:before`) from `bottom: -30px` to `bottom: -12px`.

Comment: +1 Nice solution, I was thinking about .js solution. By the way will it support IE8?

Comment: It *will* work on IE8, but not on IE7. For more support, use [this](http://selectivizr.com).

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you very much

Comment: A very late comment - but this doesn't seem to work in all cases : http://jsfiddle.net/pcn101qp/1/ demonstrates that the tooltip has a gap on all but the first line.